# How do you use caret ('^') to exclude files/folders only once in PCRE Regex syntax?

Tags: php, regex, joomla

For example I have in a conf.php file:

```
$GLOBALS["no_access"] = '^forbidden|restricted|xampp|apache\_pb';
```

blocking these files/folders from view and would like to restrict these strings (folders/files) a limited number of times. This is because this is an intranet project and there might be a folder I don't want accessed with the same name of a file or folder I do want available. Also, is it possible to select first instance, but not later?

This is for altering a component of Joomla, called eXtplorer, a file manager.

Comment: I really don't understand your question; but note that `|` has a very low precedence, so `^a|b` means "`^a` or `b`", *not* "`^a` or `^b`". That is, it will match `b` even when it's not at the start of the string. You probably want `'^forbidden|^restricted|^xampp|^apache_pb'`.

Comment: I think that `^` in this case marks the beginning of the string, not the negation of the character class

Comment: Regexps do not have a multi-char negation. You might be able to achive what you want using negative lookaheads though.

Comment: @ruakh Doing it that way or my original way with only one carot seems to 'hide' the folders and files the same. My need is to hide these folders/files without hiding later files. We will have project management folders that might include for example an index.php file I want everyone to have access for editing, but I don't want them to find the one specific to this domain and break my site.

Comment: @ThiefMaster So you can not do something like <code>'^(forbidden){1}'</code> to restrict it to the first instance of? I know this does not work, but I understand something similar is used. I will look into negative lookheads as well.

Comment: The problem is, I have no idea what you want, and no one else seems to understand what you want, either. Can you edit your question to give maybe five examples of strings that you *do* want your regex to match and maybe five examples of strings that you *don't* want your regex to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work either way but a whitelist would be safes instead of a blacklist (so you can only access directories starting with x).

What you want is a regex you can use to check if the start of a string starts with a particular pattern that can match a folder.

```
$regex = '/^(?:forbidden|restricted|xampp|apache_pb)/i';
```

In php that could look like this:

```
function startIsRestricted($string) {
    return preg_match('/^(?:forbidden|restricted|xampp|apache_pb)/i', $string);
}
```

**Edit**

Reading that discussion it sounds more like you want to restrict access to folders. In that case you may want to look into protecting directories with htaccess and htpasswd documentation on this you can find on [the apache website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/htpasswd.html) or [this website](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess3.shtml), going in to the whole of it a bit more

Doing the restriction in PHP would be unsafe...

**Edit 2**

*Code is sorta tested*; at least I do an implode now arround the array map (duh) and fixed obvious misspellings.

But it should at least give a good idea of how you can do this check recursively for each directory in a string...

```
/**
 * Function to check an entire string recursively to see if dissalowed directories are present
 * Assuming the string seperator will be a forwardslash
 *
 * @param string $string String to be evaluated against the dissalowed directory list given or else default
 * @param array $dissallow array of strings which are forbidden to be at the start of any of the directories
 * @param string $sep The seperator for the directory levels
 * 
 * @return string
 */
function test_directory ($string, array $dissallow = array('forbidden', 'restricted', 'xampp', 'apache_pb'), $sep = '/') {
    $regex  = '/^(?:' . implode('|', array_map ('preg_quote', $dissallow)) . ')/i';
    $dirs   = explode($sep, $string);

    foreach($dirs as $dir) {
        // true will mean a match is found and thus present in the beginning of a directory in $string
        if(preg_match($regex, $dir))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now I should note that regexes in these kind of cases can slow things down and it should be used too much, if a direct match with any string in the dissalow array is fine to you should do it checking each `$dir` in `$dirs` against each entry of `$dissallow`.

Comment: To be clear, we have access restrictions that will not allow other people to access this area, this is to prevent inadvertent updates to files and folders. I am using a section designed by the makers of eXtplorer that offered a simple commented out // Example: Hide files starting with ".ht" (like .htaccess):  ^\.ht as their example code. I took it further and hid other files using what I shared. This works fine, but it also will hide deeper files I might want to edit in our "intranet" tool for managing files.

Comment: Sounds like you want to recursively check a string for patterns. Regexes don't do that but I could write a function to do something like that for you...

Comment: I am not sure we need to go that deep into this unless it is fairly simple for you. I am probably getting a little deeper into this than the projects time frame allows. But, if you do send me something I will be experimenting with it at home in my down time and will likely learn something ;-)

Comment: Done, good luck with it, don't hesitate to ask or shout at me for writing bad code ;)

Comment: I have stopped using the eXtplorer for this project, but you get the correct answer for giving me a bit of schooling on this, thank you! I ended up going with http://ajaxplorer.info for the project.

Answer (score 1):

For PCRE, `^` says *Match the beginning of the string*. With the `|` operator, you're saying 'this *OR* that`.

With your stated regular expression, you will not match what you are expecting.

`/^(forbidden|restricted|xampp|apache\_pb)/i`

will match on the beginning of a line (such as a directory listing)

Comment: My code works and so does this, but it still hides all files and folders. It is looking like it might not be possible, but my goal was to add a count to this.(see other explanation)